# Per-process network usage on OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, netstat, lsof

I want to periodically poll for per-process network usage. Is there a way to do this efficiently in OSX like `netstat -p` on Linux? I know there's `lsof -i -Tqsf` but it doesn't seem to show bytes sent/received. `nettop` shows exactly what I need, but it's unparseable. According to `otool -L $(which nettop)`, the library it uses is `NetworkStatistics.framework`. Is there any information on this?

---